# SE site for numerical math?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, site-recommendation, math-se

Where is it appropriate to ask questions about numerical math and implementation? Is it [Math SE](http://math.stackexchange.com)?

I thought I saw a special SE site related to numerical math (maybe in beta), but I couldn't find it.

Comment: What do you mean by implementation, and what's the question you'd like to ask? Because I'm inclined to say yes, Math.SE is correct.

Comment: @Telthien In matlab, or c, or java, or anything. Or simply the algorithm.

Comment: @Telthien Does it mean there is no special site for numerical math? I want to ask how to do matrix inversion (not sure if too broad Q)

Comment: Then no, Math.SE is not the correct place. Math.SE is for mathematics-only questions. And yeah, that's significantly broad for Math.SE

Comment: There is the [computational sciences beta](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/), but you should read their FAQ to see if that's a suitable site.

Comment: @Oded That's what I was looking for. Thank you. If you could make that an answer...

Comment: When looking, go to http://stackexchange.com/sites - you can filter by category.

Comment: @Oded cool. I didn't know about that.  But that is not the list of all sites, isn't it?

Comment: @BЈовић - Actually, it is. All graduated and beta sites in the Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the [computational science beta](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).

> **Computational Science** is a question and answer site for questions and answers about computational methods used in technical disciplines

But before posting you should read their [FAQ](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/faq) to see if that's a suitable site.